# Is there a way to center one of the rows of a stack view to the center of container view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a stack view with two rows. First row has a label and the second row has a button. I am currently using, stackView.autoCenterInSuperview() to center the entire stack view in the middle of the screen. However, I just want the second row. i.e. the row containing the button to be on the center of the screen. Is there a way I can do this programmatically in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation you might be better off without the stack view, which is adding, as it were, a fence between your superview and your button. It would be easiest just to start with the button, center it, and then make other constraints positioning everything else based on the button.